# How to restart currently executing jar in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to “reboot” the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259343/any-way-to-reboot-the-jvm)

Is there any option to restart currently executing .jar(a complete project),by code from  inside that program

Comment: you wanted to stop a thread from execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can invoke using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

```
java -jar yourJar.jar
```

and immediately you can invoke

```
System.exit(0);
```

So launching new instance and stopping current