# A way to "Reboot" the JVM

Tags: java, jvm, tools.jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to “reboot” the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259343/any-way-to-reboot-the-jvm)

I added tools.jar in our JRE /lib/ext folder and I need to do a JVM reboot under windows. Is that possible without restarting the server?

Comment: *"I added tools.jar in our JRE /lib/ext folder"* ***Why?***

Comment: Your Question has been [Discussed Here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259343/any-way-to-reboot-the-jvm

There is not way to gracefullt restart the JVM, you can achieve such   a scenario by a class loader. I am not clear on the subject itself

Comment: do you want to reload some classes? Or what is the reason that you want to have a gracefull restart?

Comment: @Riju not a duplicate, he specifically needs solutions for windows OS

Comment: @Khez yah, the one in the link is for linux, i need one for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I added tools.jar in our JRE /lib/ext folder ...

That is a bad idea.  If you need to use stuff in 'tools.jar' you should be installing a JDK, not hacking a JRE installation.

> ... and I need to do a JVM reboot under windows. Is that possible wihtout restarting the server?

Ermm ...

If you are asking if it is possible to restart the application / server JVM without restarting the entire operating system, of course it is!

If you are asking if you need to restart the JVM to get it to see new stuff in '/lib/ext', then the answer is yes.  The JVM reads that directory on startup and won't notice files that are written there while it is running.

If you are asking how a JVM can reboot itself, see the linked question.

If you are asking how to restart the JVM / service from the outside, the answer is (probably) via the Windows service control GUI ... depending on which version of Windows you are using.  (And that's not a *programming* question ...)

Comment: ok so how do I restart the JVM?

Comment: I've already covered that.

Answer (score 0):

Server process typically runs on top of Java Runtime inside JVM. 
even if you succeed to re-boot JVM  OR killing the Java process will result in the server process to terminate.