# How to reboot the JVM under windows

Tags: java, windows

How do I restart the **whole JVM** in our **Windows Server** which have JRE, without restarting the OS?

Is there something like:

> java -restart

Or this is not possible. The idea is that I added **tool.jar** in `/lib/ext` folder of the JRE and that I need to restart the JVM.

Comment: There is nothing like a JVM running in an OS. Instead several independent instances do run. Just make sure to stop all running Java applications (java*.exe) and restart them if necessary.

Comment: I think your issue like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259343/any-way-to-reboot-the-jvm

Comment: Just got into case when I run java profiler (Visual VM 1.3.8) and I see my Java app running having PID 3232. When I go to "Windows Task Manager"->"Services"->sort by PID there is no PID 3232. Then I go to processes and try to kill "Javaw" and it helped to remove that process 3232.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/programmatically-restart-java

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Java` process runs on demand as and when you want to run it. It's not a daemon. You need to stop the `Java` process manually (kill it) if it doesn't end gracefully.

Comment: As you start the JVM, it _should_ load that. You wouldn't need to worry about system libraries. You need to add your own jars (if any) to the classpath when you start the `Java` process.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259343/any-way-to-reboot-the-jvm